# My cookie does not set in my browser, How can I fixed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, jwt

I've working with jwt and cookies I don't  why my cookie does not set in my browser.
If I do this in postman works properly, create cookie and looks well, but when I do this in my browser with my react form, cookie does not set.

Please any advice

This my frontend code

```
const onSubmit = useCallback(async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setStatus('pending')
    setError(null)
    const credentials = {
      email: values.email,
      password: values.password
    }
    console.log(credentials)
    try {
      const res = await API.post(LOGIN_API, credentials)
      console.log(res.data)
      if (res.data.success) {
        setStatus('success')
        navigate('/')
      } else {
        setStatus('error')
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setError(error)
    }
  }, [values, error, navigate])
```

my backend

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  const text = 'SELECT user_id, password, email FROM user_account WHERE email=$1;'
  const values = [req.body.email]
  try {
    const response = await client.query(text, values)
    const match = await bcrypt.checkPassword(req.body.password, response.rows[0].password)
    if (match) {
      res.cookie("access_token", jwt.sign({ id: response.rows[0].user_id }, jwtSecret), { httpOnly: true })
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: "Logged in successfully" })
    } else {
      res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: "Credentials are not valid" })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack)
  }
}
```

And then here my axios instance

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_API_URL
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can only be set if you load a resource by a browser, no through JavaScript. There is no way to set httponly cookie this way.
Usually jwt tokens are stored in localStorage